# Can I expect a probe thermometer to still work if I cut it short?

Tags: thermal, thermistor

I have a kitchen probe thermometer, a bit like this one

[image]

It's overly long for my purposes, and takes an annoyingly long time to record a stable value. I assume this is because it takes a while for the heat to travel up the shaft.

I have no idea what the electrical properties of the metal shaft are, or if there is any internal structure at all. If I simply cut the probe short (to a couple of inches or so), can I expect it to still read an accurate temperature?

(I guess the electrical resistance/resistivity of the metal might matter, or it might not, depending on how these things operate? Or maybe there's internal structure which could easily be short-circuited?)

Comment: Very likely you will kill it

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model of that specific thermometer?

Comment: The actual sensor is down at the tip. If you cut it off, it won't work any more.

Comment: what exactly does this mean? `annoyingly long time to record a stable value` .... how are you using it?

Comment: You will kill it. Also, the sensor will be at the very tip, with a wire running up the shaft. The time to stabilise has nothing to do with the length of the shaft.

Comment: science: does a lighter raise the temp faster when held on the shaft or tip? if the tip is more sensitive, you can't trim the shaft...

Comment: The purpose of those is to measure the interior of meat; if you just want to measure the surface temperature get an IR thermometer.